# I made a survey in SharePoint 2003 and now I went to attach a document to it. Is this possible?

Tags: file, survey, share, powerpoint

I am in the middle of making a survey on SharePoint for all employees at my bank. I want them to view a PowerPoint then take the survey. Is there a way to attach a PowerPoint to this survey?

Answer (score 0):

I copied a link to the PowerPoint in the survey description.